# Google ReCaptcha verify with php

Tags: recaptcha

I have tried to verify ReCaptcha like this, but its not working. It won't let send email and when "I am not robot" is clicked, nothing happens.

```
if(trim($_POST['getResponse']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $getResponse = trim($_POST['getResponse']);
}
```

My ReCaptcha PHP code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mykeyhere"></div>
    <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Kinnita,et sa ei ole robot.</span>
</div>

<span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Sisesta turvakood.</span>
</div>

<div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Saada', 'bootstrapwp'); ?>" name="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary" title="Saada!" />
    <input type="reset" value="<?php _e('Tühjenda väljad', 'bootstrapwp'); ?>" class="btn btn-danger" title="Tühjenda väljad." />
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok,got it woking with this code

```
     if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
    $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
  }
  if(!$captcha){
    echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
    exit;
  }
$response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=key&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        if($response.success==false)
        {
          echo '<h2>You are spammer ! Get the @$%K out</h2>';
        }else
        {
          echo '<h2>Thanks for posting comment.</h2>';
        }
```

only problem now is that error and success messages are displayed on another page,how to display these error and success messages inside form?